# Inserted images into the report has grey background

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oraclereports

When I'm inserting our company logo into Oracle Report there is a grey background on the logo. The logo is file type BMP, I have tried different file types like JPEG and TIFF as well. The issue still remains the grey background.

Below is the example of that grey background.
[image]

As you can see the portion which has the logo has a grey background whereas the background of the report is white. This is totally against our company guidelines and I've been told to find a solution for this. Please advise how can I remove the grey background.

Thanks

Comment: How does logo look like outside of the report? Does it have a white background? Try to edit the image (see the **brightness** effect - enlarge its value).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the background of the image then use an editing tool like photoshop and then remove the background and save the image as png then convert into bmp and then use it in your report.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in Forms 11/12C. I create the image in GIMP. If the image contains just one layer in GIMP, the problem occur. If I create a background layer in GIMP that is white and then export as gif, the imported image in Forms will have white background.